# How can I get the test suite name (Junit)

Tags: java, junit

I have two test suites with multiple test cases. Inside one of those test cases, I need to know the name of the caller test suite.

I tried to get it using getStackTrace() and Junit Rules(TestWatcher) but I did not get the test suite name.

```
    // FirstTestSuite.java
    @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @SuiteClasses({ TestCase1.class, TestCase2.class })
    public class FirstTestSuite {

    }

    // SecondTestSuite.java
    @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @SuiteClasses({ TestCase3.class, TestCase4.class })
    public class SecondTestSuite {

    }

    // TestCase1.java
    public class TestCase1 {

    @Test
    public void testTestCase1(){
    //code
    getTestSuiteName();
    }

    public void getTestSuiteName(){
      // How can I get the test suite name which called me
    }
}
```

Comment: Smells like X/Y problem, why do you need that name?

Comment: Just thinking loud here..can you have your class `TestCase1.java` implement [RunListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) and override `testStarted` and call `getAnnotations()` on the `Description` object and see what it shows ?

Comment: It shows only this text in the Console: testStarted: [@org.junit.Test(timeout=0, expected=class org.junit.Test$None)]